# Getting Specific characters from a file in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So my question comes from wanting to get specific numbers from a text file using batch. Here is the text file I am trying to read

```
        Force user logoff how long after time expires?:       Never
        Minimum password age (days):                          0
        Maximum password age (days):                          40
        Minimum password length:                              7
        Length of password history maintained:                None
        Lockout threshold:                                    Never
        Lockout duration (minutes):                           30
        Lockout observation window (minutes):                 30
        Computer role:                                        WORKSTATION
        The command completed successfully.
```

As you can see it is just the standard output of the `net accounts` command in batch. What I am trying to do is secure a computers password policy but also make a back up if they want to undo it. I have the script to secure it but the undoing it is the hard part. This out put is from the backup I created. I am trying to get the old Minimum password age, maximum password age, and minimum password length from this file. They are currently 0, 40, and 7.

I am realatively new to batch programing so any help would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45181780.txt"
FOR %%a IN (minpassage maxpaxxage minpasslen) DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%a"=="Minimum password age (days)" SET /a minpassage=%%b
 IF "%%a"=="Maximum password age (days)" SET /a maxpassage=%%b
 IF "%%a"=="Minimum password length" SET /a minpasslen=%%b
)
ECHO Min pass age=%minpassage%
ECHO Max pass age=%maxpassage%
ECHO Min pass len=%minpasslen%

:: adding in the "net account" command
:: Note that this command is merely ECHOed for testing.
:: If all seems in order, remove the "ECHO " from the following command

ECHO net accounts /minpwlen:%minpasslen%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q45181780.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Clear the variables to be used (just in case they've alreadt got an assigned value)

Read each line of the file, tokenising on `:` and assign the first token to `%%a`, the second to `%%b`. If `%%a` matches the significant string, use `set /a` to set the variable (since these data items are numeric)

Report.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried using those variables in a `net` but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried `net accounts /minpwlen:%minpasslen%` but it doesn't seem to work. It says "command completed successfully" but nothing changes. Any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is normal practice for batch files to contain a `setlocal` command at the beginning. This command sets a local environment that is then altered by the batch and eventually backed out when the batch terminates, restoring the original environment unchanged. It's done this way in order that the environment is kept clean, without worrying about which variables may have been set up by other batches.

Comment: If you *deliberately* want to change the values in the environment for *this particular* cmd instance, then either remove the `setlocal` command (which will cause *any* change made by the batch to "stick" in this `cmd` instance) *or* execute a command `endlocal&set needth=%needthis%&set needthat=%needthat%` (all must be on the same physical line) just before exiting whether by reaching end-of-file, `goto :eof` or `exit/b`. This uses a parsing trick whereby the the entire line is resolved & then executed; ending the local environment and then setting the variables to their then-current values

Comment: sorry for the confusion but I am trying to use net accounts within the same batch script that I get the variable.

Comment: Not really sure what's happening. I've added the command you apparently want to execute into the code. The `net` command should be `echo`ed to the screen. Remove the `echo` keyword to activate the `net` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, *(language specific)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (min max len) Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('Find "imum"^<"accountinfo.txt"'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do If Not Defined min (Set "min=%%B"
) Else If Not Defined max (Set "max=%%B") Else Set "len=%%B"
For %%A In (min max len) Do Set %%A
Pause
```

Please remember to change accountinfo.txt to the name of your actual net accounts output file.

---

You should also be able to just read the values without outputting to a text file too:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (min max len) Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('Net Accounts^|Find "imum"'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do If Not Defined min (Set "min=%%B"
) Else If Not Defined max (Set "max=%%B") Else Set "len=%%B"
For %%A In (min max len) Do Set %%A
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Compo's 2nd batch I thought why not get the variable names from the text:

```
> type PassMinMax.cmd
@Echo off
For /F "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%A in ('net accounts^|find "imum"'
) Do For /f "tokens=1-3" %%C in ("%%A") Do @Set /A %%D_%%C_%%E=%%B
Set Pass
```

Sample Output:

```
> PassMinMax.cmd
password_Maximum_age=42
password_Minimum_age=0
password_Minimum_length=0
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by parsing each line with a regex in PowerShell.

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path ./parsepw.txt

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    if ($line -match '\s*Minimum password age \(days\):\s*([0-9]*)\w*') { $minpwage = [int]$Matches[1] }
    elseif ($line -match '\s*Maximum password age \(days\):\s*([0-9]*)\w*') { $maxpwage = [int]$Matches[1] }
    elseif ($line -match '\s*Minimum password length:\s*([0-9]*)\w*') { $minpwlen = [int]$Matches[1] }
}

$minpwage
$maxpwage
$minpwlen
```